# Пустой $_POSTмассив в php

Tags: php

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <form action="handler.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="text" name="test">
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="send">
        </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

handler.php

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
echo print_r($_GET);
echo print_r($_POST);
echo print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Выводит пусты массивы, а если заменить method на get то массивы $_GET и $_REQUEST будут содержать значения.
Почему с post не работает?

Comment: handler.php у вас вообще ничего выводить не должен - там отсутствует открывающий тег. Пожалуйста, проверьте, что _в точности_ такое содержимое файлов, как в вопросе, воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: Разумеется в начале есть <?php

Comment: Не хочу вас расстраивать, но только что проверил у себя и всё нормально выводит

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в nginx или apache.
Nginx при редиректе с https на http и наоборот не отправляет переменные post к примеру. С apache тоже самое.
Необходимы настройки веб сервера